# Extra spacing below my in-line images

Tags: html, css, image

### Background

I am creating a video gallery using the ShadowBox jQuery plugin.  To do this, I am creating rows of inline images using `display:inline-block`.  The user will be able to upload a video as well as thumbnail images to accompany the video.  The thumbnail's max size is 240x160 pixels.

What I want to do is have a black border around each gallery thumbnail "slot" with the user's uploaded thumbnail residing inside of that "slot", so if the user uploads a 240x160 thumbnail, the thumbnail will fill up the "slot" completely, and if they upload a smaller image, the thumbnail will still be in the "slot" with some extra spacing around it.

Here's an example of where I am right now: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/HvZ5p/

The problem is that there is extra spacing below my thumbnails and I'm not sure why. If you inspect the code you will see that there is an extra 5 pixels lurking below the image and I'm not sure where it's coming from.  The grey part below the image should be directly BEHIND the image so that in the case the user uploads a smaller thumbnail, there will be grey-background space around it, but for some reason it is too tall.  Any suggestions?

### HTML

```
<div class="inline">
    <div class="bg-thumb">
        <div class="cell-thumb">
            <a href="#" rev="#nvcCaption#" class="shadow">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8330/8135703920_f2302b8415_m.jpg" class="thumbImg" alt="Thumb" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vcCaption">Caption</div>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    <div class="bg-thumb">
        <div class="cell-thumb">
            <a href="#" rev="#nvcCaption#" class="shadow">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8330/8135703920_f2302b8415_m.jpg" class="thumbImg" alt="Thumb" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vcCaption">Caption</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 50px 0 50px;
}
.vcCaption {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.inline {
    display:inline-block;   
}
.bg-thumb {
    width:250px;
    height:170px;   
}
.bg-thumb {
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.cell-thumb {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:5px solid #000;
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
}
.thumbImg {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:160px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your thumbnails:

```
.thumbImg {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:160px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HvZ5p/1/)**

The default value of [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is `baseline`, but for your needs you'll want the images to align to the top.

Another option would be to set the font size to zero on the containing div like:

```
.cell-thumb {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:5px solid #000;
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
    font-size:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HvZ5p/8/)**

Comment: Wow that did it. Thanks!  Was it the `<a>` tag that was causing this? How did this fix the problem?

Comment: @Shaun - I added a short explanation of why you needed to specify the vertical-align rule.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it was the oldest and most detailed, although all of these solutions worked perfectly.  Thanks everyone! Problem fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to your image will solve that.

```
.thumbImg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:160px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you this works as well as `vertical-align:top`. Good to know

Answer (score 1):

the anchor tag is by default an inline element which gives it extra spacing, set it to a block element and give it some width and height!

```
.cell-thumb a {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: This works as well as the other answers.  Thanks for the alternate solution.  I think the problem definitely stemmed from the `<a>` tag

Comment: @Shaun No problem, yes it was the <a> causing it, you could see it in the console by highlighting it. I use this fix all of the time! )

Answer (score 1):

Images will by default display as `inline-block` (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img-display) meaning that they will sits on an inline level block - or text line if you prefer.

Either set the `font-size` and/or `line-height` to `0` or in this case simply set the image to display at block level (`display: block;`).